# Вывод из БД в JSON

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте! Вот мой код пхп:

```
$query = 'SELECT * from infourl';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Invalid Query, " . mysql_error());
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result) ) {
   $rows['info'] = array($row);   
} 
echo json_encode($rows);
```

И вот результат:

```
{  
   "info":[  
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "url":"http:\/\/video2.php",
         "title":"Two Video",
         "comment":"Two Comment"
      }
   ]
}
```

Но у меня в базе 2 записи, но выводит только одну.Почему????Помогите плиз.

Comment: Так вы на каждой итерации цикла перезаписываете значение в `$rows['info']`

Comment: на другом языке я бы создал цикл фор, а как здесь можно реализовать?? Если не сложно, то пример кода.

Answer (score 1):

в общем можно так сделать

```
$query = 'SELECT * from infourl';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if(!$result) {
   error_log(mysqli_error()); // не стоит полить запрос и странно зачемвы используете mysql_error?
}
$rows['info'] = iterator_to_array(mysqli_fetch_object($result)); 
echo json_encode($rows);
```

хотя может даже лучше использовать `mysqli_fetch_array` но я не знаком с `mysqli` так что извините. Если кто то может предугодать вернёт ли `mysqli_fetch_array` полностью массив строк то напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: Нечего писать фигурные скобки вокруг каждого оператора. Вы имеете в виду вот это - mysqli_fetch_all ?

Comment: @splash58 coding style и стандарты psr1 и psr2

Comment: Вы правы: The body of each structure MUST be enclosed by braces. This standardizes how the structures look, and reduces the likelihood of introducing errors as new lines get added to the body. Теперь вам надо почитать, например, тут -  http://gramma.ru/, чтобы грамотно писать и по-русски :))

Comment: @splash58 если для вас знание русского и грамотность письма. Выше чем программирование и знания математики, абстракция мышления вам больше подойдет хабр чем СО... если человек безграмотен и выражает свои мысли в чем то другом это еще не повод оскарблять его... Я же не советую вам заучить кодинг стаил, что бы вы код писали такой который можно прочитать, про документирование своего кода вообще не говорю, для вас же не обязательно даже скобка что там о документации говорить, и так все поймут.

Comment: Я думаю, что здесь не очень место для этого диспута. Если хотите его продолжить, думаю, можно перебраться в чат. Заодно расскажите, что в моем сообщении было оскорбительным для вас